# MATLAB scatter plots and legends

Tags: matlab, legend, scatter-plot

I have some data that I am looking to plot in a scatter plot. The data is gathered from two sensors, so I have `channel1` and `channel2`. The sensors are placed in various locations, so, `location1`, `location2` and so on, up to location 9.

The data looks something like this is the .csv file:

| Channel1 | Channel2 | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4255 | 7513 | 1 |
| 4277 | 6978 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 975 | 7510 | 2 |
| 552 | 6587 | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2301 | 2145 | 3 |

The code below seems to plot the colours for the groups. Is this correct?

```
scatter(Channel1,Channel2,[], location)
```

But I am not able to get the legend correct to show which colour relates to which location, and I hope someone can help.